# Is the following sentence grammatically incorrect and is it used colloquially?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, questions, auxiliary-verbs, subordinate-clauses

> (1) I don't know what graph theory is.

According to the grammar, I believe it should be:

> (2) I don't know what is graph theory.

But is it spoken colloquially the way I wrote it in (1)?

---

Grammar note:

We don't find subject-auxiliary inversion if the *wh*-word is the subject:

- Who killed Cock Robin?
- Who is coming to dinner?

We could assume the same is true for:

- What is graph theory?

So it seems that we might assume that the embedded questions look like this:

- I don't know who killed Cock Robin.
- I don't know who is coming to dinner.
- I don't know what is graph theory.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Interrogative sentences with wh-clauses in the middle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/465229/interrogative-sentences-with-w-clauses-in-the-middle/465240#465240).

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is correct:

> I don't know what graph theory is.

It is wrong to say "I don't know what is graph theory.", although it is such a common mistake with non-native speakers that you will see it quite frequently.

In general I believe the order is reversed when the unknown is the object - in other words the verb and the known noun would be in the same order as they would in a statement. So:

> Somebody  killed Cock Robin
>
> I don't know who killed Cock Robin.

The unknown is the subject so verb before noun.

> Cock Robin  killed somebody
>
> I don't know who Cock Robin killed.

The unknown is the object, so noun before verb.

In your example:

> Graph theory  is something
>
> I don't know what Graph theory is.

Noun before verb because the unknown is the object.

For your other examples:

> Somebody  is coming to dinner.
>
> I don't know who is coming to dinner.

Verb before noun because the unknown is the subject.

Answer (score -1):

This is correct.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/i-dont-know-how-what

Example #3 clearly states I don't know what .... is playing at.

Comment: You say "this is correct" but you might want to clarify what "this" is referring to.